# accessing structures using indexers?

Tags: c#, struct

can v access an array of struct inside a class using indexers??

for example here..

```
class sample
{
  public struct foo
  {
     int x;
     int y;
  }
  foo[] anyname=new foo[100];
  public foo this [int i]
  {
    get
    {
     // code here
    }
    set
    {
     // code here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should do a bit of reading on .net naming conventions. When to use upper/lowercase names, what the prefixes are used for (In particular `T` is used for template parameters)

Answer (score 2):

You can return (or assign) a *copy* of the item:

```
    public foo this[int i]
    {
        get { return T[i]; }
        set { T[i] = value; }
    }
```

Notes;

- `T` is usually a bad name, as the *convention* is that `T` refers to generics
- `struct` is almost always misused; make sure you know what `struct` *means* before deciding to use it - one thing it *doesn't* mean is "a lightweight object without methods", which is the oft-reported (and entirely incorrect) myth; in particular, *mutable* `struct`s are usually a very bad idea

Comment: agree 100% with naming of T, i had to read 3 times over it, i tought all the times the T is generic

Comment: +1 on the copy point, along with structs cast to interfaces and structs accessed through getters, this is an oft-forgotten point.

Comment: A 2D vector as in his example is one of the good usecases for a struct though.

Comment: @CodeInChaos yes, which is why I didn't say "don't", but rather "make sure"... and I'm also thinking of the *long tail* in my answer, so what applies to the *next* reader may be different

Answer (score 0):

return this.T[i];

this.T[i] = value;